# onChange in React doesn't capture the last character of text in Input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component

[See GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VxgN.gif) I'm building a simple search by tags in React. You have 10 posts on the page and each post has a tag. For example there are 2 tags "Cat" and "Cry" All tags are stored in local memory, no BD. If I input in my search a letter "C", then the page correctly renders posts with the "Cat" and "Cry" tags. But when I write "Ct" in the search bar, it renders again these 2 posts by the first letter but does not capture the subsequent letter "T". Please see GIF attached.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import CardList from "../../features/CardList";
import SearchInput from "../../features/SearchInput";
import fetchFilms from "../../api/FetchAPI";
import { formatData } from "../../services/formatData";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { filterTags, getFilmsList } from "../../store/actions";

function PageList() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [request, setRequest] = useState("");

  async function getFilms() {
    const data = await fetchFilms();
    const dataFormat = formatData(data);
    dispatch(getFilmsList(dataFormat));
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getFilms();
  }, []);

  function requestHandler(e) {
    console.log('request', request)
    setRequest(e.target.value);
    dispatch(filterTags(request));
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <SearchInput onChange={requestHandler} />
      <CardList />
    </div>
  );
}

export default PageList;
```

I expect that if I have tags Cat, Cry and I input Ct then no results show. I tried every solution offered on this forum with a similar title.

Comment: Implement the `dispatch` on a `useEffect` that has `request` as a dependency. State updates are only reflected on component's next render and that's why you are passing a stale state to `filterTags`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `onChange`, use `onKeyPress` event. Also, `request` state will not update right after you have set its value, because it is an asynchronous operation.

An alternative would be to `dispatch` your action directly with the input's value. Like so:

```
function requestHandler(e) {
    dispatch(filterTags(e.target.value));
  }
```

```
<SearchInput onKeyPress={requestHandler} />
```

[onKeyPress docs](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeypress.asp)

Comment: Changing from `onChange` to `onKeyPress` doesn't change how the React component lifecycle works. The `request` state still won't have updated in `requestHandler` when calling `dispatch(filterTags(request));`.

Comment: That's true. What could work though is using the input's value to dispatch the action directly

Comment: Just edited my answer @DrewReese